# SQL injection in PHP Phalcon

Tags: php, sql-injection, phalcon

I just learning SQL injection and try to inject my PHP based code (with PHP Phalcon framework). I try to do SQL injection in my login. However, when I try to do the injection, I cannot do it and I do not know whether it is caused by my code is already robust from SQL injection or that I do the injection in wrong way.

My login section contains of email and password. For the email section, I insert `test@test.com' or 1=1` and insert some random password.

However, there is an error message showing something like this:

```
Scanning error before ' LIMIT :APL0:' when parsing: SELECT [Test\\Models\\Login].* FROM [TEST\\Models\\Login] WHERE email='test@test.com' or 1=1 --' LIMIT :APL0: (119)
```

Here is the verify login code:

```
public function verifyLogin ($email, $password) {
    $records = $this->findFirst("email='$email'");
    if ($records && sha1($password)==$records->password) {
        return ($records->id);
    }
    return (false);
}
```

How to know whether it is my injection that is wrong or the code is already robust? And if the injection is still wrong, how to fix it?

Comment: Including the code where you actually build your statement would be a thing though. Basically, Phalcon uses single queries only, so you can only execute one statement per call. If you are using the parameter binding, you should be on the safe site.

Comment: I have added the code @maio290

Comment: Try: `test@test.com' or 1=1 or 1='` for your email injection. This should produce valid sql code, if your injection is successful. And amend your question, if the error changes.

Comment: the injection success, however why it is needed to add additional `or 1=`? @jh1711

Comment: The additional `1=` is not important, it could be done other ways. But the opening single quote is needed to make the final SQL statement valid. A very simple query could look like this: `SELECT * from TABLE where email = '$email'`;` If you have full control over `$email` you (as an attacker)  can close the single quote, and inject your payload; but you need to make sure that the entire statement is valid. With my injection the where statement means: Is the email valid? who cares! OR 1=1? that's true.  OR 1 = "". who cares?

Comment: Even though code you wrote is in deed not safe from sql injection phalcon orm will partially prevent it - limiting operation to one, for example its impossible to put there update or delete query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you wrote your code irrespective of whether it is Phalcon or not is prone to SQL injection. I am not sure if you actually *want* to perform SQL injection in the script above or you are trying to figure out ways to protect against it.

If it is the latter, you can always bind your parameters:

```
public function verifyLogin ($email, $password) {
    $record = $this->findFirst(
        'conditions' => 'email = :email:',
        'bind'       => [
            'email' => $email,
         ],
    );

    if ($record && sha1($password) == $records->password) {
        return ($records->id);
    }

    return false;
}
```

The above code uses bound parameters, a feature of PDO that offers better security against SQL injections.

Comment: Parameter binding isn't a feature of PDO, it's a database feature ;)